# How to extract exactly three observations with biggest count

Tags: r, dplyr, radix

How to extract only three observations that are top observations with respect to some variable, ex. count (`n` var in example data below)? I would like to avoid arranging rows so I thought I could use `dplyr::min_rank`.

```
ex <- structure(list(code = c("17.1", "6.2", "151.5", "78.1", "88.1", 
"95.1", "45.2", "252.2"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), n = c(6L, 
5L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

ex %>% 
  filter(min_rank(desc(n)) <= 3)
```

But if there are ties, it can give more than 3 observations. For example, the command above returns five rows:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  code     id     n
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 17.1      1     6
2 151.5     3     8
3 78.1      4    10
4 88.1      5     6
5 252.2     8     6
```

How can I then extract exactly 3 observations? (no matter which observation is returned in case of ties)

Comment: You can try 
`ex %>%
 arrange(desc(n)) %>%
 slice(1:3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `row_number` that can take a column as argument

```
ex %>% 
  filter(row_number(desc(n)) <= 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   code     id     n
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 17.1      1     6
#2 151.5     3     8
#3 78.1      4    10
```

Answer (score 1):

In  base R, we can use

```
ex[tail(order(ex$n),3), ]
```